# Python sys.argv indexerror list index out of range

Tags: python

When I use splitter_freqy.py to split my .dat filem I meet the following problem.

line 5 name=str(sys.argv[position+1])
indexerror list index out of range

I use ubuntu and the command is

python3.6 splitter_freq.py abc.dat

This is the splitter_freq.py

```
import sys

arguments = len(sys.argv) - 1
position = 1
name = str(sys.argv[position+1])
while (arguments > position):       # changed >= to > to avoid error
    bench_freq_names = []
    path0 = "./%s/"%name+sys.argv[position]
    position = position+1
    print("the input file is ",path0) 
    c_0 = open(path0,'r')
    header=c_0.readline()
    l_0 = c_0.readline()
    w_0 = l_0.split()
    bench_name = w_0[1]
    freq_value = w_0[3]
    path_out = path0.split("/")
    path_out = path_out[-1].split(".")
    print("the benchmark name is ",bench_name)
    print("the freq value is ",freq_value) 
    bench_freq_names.append([bench_name,freq_value])
    output_file = "./%s/"%name+path_out[0]+"_"+bench_name+"_"+freq_value+".txt"
    m = open(output_file,'a')
    print(header.rstrip('\n'),file=m)
    print(l_0.rstrip('\n'),file=m)
    for l_0 in c_0: #read lines one by one
        w_0 = l_0.split()
        if (w_0[1] == bench_name and w_0[3] == freq_value):
            print(l_0.rstrip('\n'),file=m)
        else: #new_bench_name or new freq_value
            m.close() #close file
            bench_name = w_0[1] #update bench
            freq_value = w_0[3] #update freq
            print("the benchmark name is ",bench_name) 
            print("the freq value is ",freq_value)
            output_file = "./%s/"%name+path_out[0]+"_"+bench_name+"_"+freq_value+".txt"
            m = open(output_file,'a')
            if [bench_name,freq_value] not in bench_freq_names:
                bench_freq_names.append([bench_name,freq_value])
                print(header.rstrip('\n'),file=m)
            print(l_0.rstrip('\n'),file=m)
c_0.close()
m.close()
```

Comment: What is unclear to you about the error? Why do you think the index should not be out of range?

Comment: Modify this line - `name = str(sys.argv[position])`  and check again?

Comment: Are you already try to print the `sys.argv` first? To know the content of the sys.argv

Comment: NameError 'c_0' is not defined

Comment: why not use `for arg in sys.argv[1:]` instead of `while (arguments > position)` and without `arguments`, `position` - but with `arg` instead of `sys.argv[position]`

Comment: `sys.argv` is list of strings so there is no need to use `str()`

Comment: I don't understand what you want to get with `name=str(sys.argv[position+1])` - as for me this value seems useless, You could use directly `arg` from code `for arg in sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: code could be more readable if you would use `f-string` instead of `%` - `f"./{name}/{arg}"` and `f"./{name}/{path_out[0]}_{bench_name}_{freq_value}.txt"`